# mysql is slow and crashes ! need suggestion on optimization

Tags: mysql, database, optimization, database-performance

few months ago i launched a website, as number of concurrent users raised i noticed my server got slow and sometimes mysql made server crash ( about 7000 concurrent users ) !

i have a powerful server with 32gb of ram and a xeon quad-core CPU dedicated to 1 website, also the programming is neat and lightweight, there is nothing special on DB side ... just some simple tables, no triggers, no complex relations.

can you guys suggest anything that i can do to improve mysql performance or to replace it with ? im hoping for some same experiences and case studies from you.

*Update* one of the tables that slows down the performance is where i collect and compare user IPs, so that if the IP is new, i add a new record on this table and store users IP ... i feel im doing it wrong ... so im open to constructive criticism :-D is it even good to add index in this table considering im inserting in it a lot (but not often as i use search in it ... ) ?

Comment: have you added indexes to tables?

Comment: Take the slow query and run the explain statment on it. Do something like EXPLAIN 'slow query' and paste the query and output here.

Comment: Oh another question do you check this IP address often and then insert? For example do you check every connection for a new IP address? Post your table structure here as well please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is a bit vague in that it is a general problem that your are experiencing however there are some steps that you can take to determine the underlying cause of the problem.

**Profile the hardware:**

Check your cpu, memory and disk io statistics to eliminate hardware issues. High Disk IO in particular can cause severe performance issues. There are several articles on how to profile your hardware out there. Go google it for your platform.

**Profile the SQL queries:**

Enable the slow query log on the MySQL server check this link for more information: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/slow-query-log.html.

Identify your queries that run the longest and do a EXPLAIN statement on these queries.If you find that most of your queries that are slow are SELECT/read type statements you might be missing indexes. If you find that UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE(writes) are causing the problems you might have too many indexes or you are facing a IO bottleneck on the disks.

*Remember this rule:* adding more indexes is going to slow down insert/deletes/updates and speed up select.

The bottom line is that you need to profile the server and the database to determine where you need to make changes to increase performance and scalability. Once you have identified the problem areas then you can take more specific actions.

Let us know if you need help optimizing your server based on your findings.

Answer (score 0):

add index to the tables of your database. if tables are id based then make that column  a unique index for records. This will help!

Comment: 7000 is less although other sites have 500000 rows in a table but they work like charm...

Comment: This is a blanket statement and not true. Adding indexes will speed up select/read queries but slow down insert/updates/deletes/write queries. Also what if it is a hardware problem such as excessive disk queues? Disks are the most overlooked part of database design and is sometimes the cause of most performance problems.

Comment: he said help me in any way for betterment of my database. Adding Index to a table which is highly populated is necessary! and i am a jquery, javascript , css and HTML programmer. I use data tables less for my codes and hence, have less knowledge.

Comment: I understand that adding a index might be a performance increase for reads but for writes it is a performance killer. If you have 5 indexes on a table for every insert the database engine has to do 6 writes to the disk 1 for the table and 5 for the indexes. The same principle counts for deletes and updates. Remember indexes are seperate datastructures from the table that stores data by themselves they are NOT part of the table. They usually are tree structures on disk.

Comment: yeah you said right but man if owner of web is wise he will also know that tables can be made in id-based structures where you can add unique-index to that column and updating, deleting e.t.c. records become faster and efficient!

Comment: if you are modeling a database without unique indexes on your tables rather use a NoSQL or other alternative. It is essential for a database to have uniqueness preserved. Just keep in mind that a adding a id does not make your data unique at all you can still have duplicate data.

Answer (score 0):

Look into [explain](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html). It will give you indication as to what indexes are required.

Comment: thanks for that man! i didn't even know that because i use to add index to each table manually :) .........

Comment: EXPLAIN will only help you optimise your queries which are missing indexes. Not going to magically suggest where to add them on a table.

Comment: It tells you how the query is going to be processed. i.e. What columns are used and hence where to place the indexes.